# Replacing deprecated Source.actorPublisher by Source.fromGraph - how to limit?

Tags: scala, websocket, akka, akka-stream, server-push

Now that `Source.actorPublisher` is deprecated, I wanted to find an adequate replacement.

Warning: I am still an Akka newb, trying to find my way!

Basically what I have is a websocket, where the server pushes a new message every second.

Relevant code:

```
// OLD, deprecated way
//val source: Source[TextMessage.Strict, ActorRef] = Source.actorPublisher[String](Props[KeepAliveActor]).map(i => TextMessage(i))

// NEW way
val sourceGraph: Graph[SourceShape[TextMessage.Strict], NotUsed] = new KeepAliveSource
val source: Source[TextMessage.Strict, NotUsed] = Source.fromGraph(sourceGraph)

val requestHandler: HttpRequest => HttpResponse =
{
  case req @ HttpRequest(GET, Uri.Path("/ws"), _, _, _) =>
    req.header[UpgradeToWebSocket] match
    {
      case Some(upgrade) => upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(Sink.ignore, source)
      case None => HttpResponse(400, entity = "Not a valid websocket request")
    }
  case r: HttpRequest =>
    r.discardEntityBytes() // important to drain incoming HTTP Entity stream
    HttpResponse(404, entity = "Unknown resource!")
}
```

the old actor: (Basically taken from: [Actorpublisher as source in handleMessagesWithSinkSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815784/actorpublisher-as-source-in-handlemessageswithsinksource))

```
case class KeepAlive()

class KeepAliveActor extends ActorPublisher[String]
{
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  implicit val ec = context.dispatcher

  val tick = context.system.scheduler.schedule(1 second, 1 second, self, KeepAlive())

  var cnt = 0
  var buffer = Vector.empty[String]

  override def receive: Receive =
  {
    case KeepAlive() =>
    {
      cnt = cnt + 1
      if (buffer.isEmpty && totalDemand > 0)
      {
        onNext(s"${cnt}th Message from server!")
      }
      else {
        buffer :+= cnt.toString
        if (totalDemand > 0) {
          val (use,keep) = buffer.splitAt(totalDemand.toInt)
          buffer = keep
          use foreach onNext
        }
      }
    }
  }

  override def postStop() = tick.cancel()
}
```

The old way works like a charm.

Now the new code, based on a GraphStage

```
class KeepAliveSource extends GraphStage[SourceShape[TextMessage.Strict]]
{
  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic =
  {
    new TimerGraphStageLogic(shape)
    {
      // All state MUST be inside the GraphStageLogic,
      // never inside the enclosing GraphStage.
      // This state is safe to access and modify from all the
      // callbacks that are provided by GraphStageLogic and the
      // registered handlers.

      private var counter = 1
      setHandler(out, new OutHandler
      {
        override def onPull(): Unit =
        {
          push(out, TextMessage(counter.toString))
          counter += 1
          schedulePeriodically(None, 1 second)
        }
      })
    }
  }

  val out: Outlet[TextMessage.Strict] = Outlet("KeepAliveSource")
  override def shape: SourceShape[TextMessage.Strict] = SourceShape(out)
}
```

For whatever reason, this still floods me, although I had assumed the `schedulePeriodically(None, 1 second)` would add a delay of 1 second between each message. I am obviously wrong though.

Increasing this value does not change the fact that my poor browser can't handle the requests and crashes (I can see it in the log of the `simple websocket client`)

Answer (score 0):

That `schedulePeriodically` call does not affect the behaviour of your stage. Whenever a downstream stage requests a message, the `onPull` handler is called, and a message is `push`ed out straightaway. This is why you see no throttling whatsoever.

Although the `GraphStage` DSL (the one you chose) is very flexible, it is also more difficult to get right. For simple tasks like this it would be better to leverage higher level stages that Akka provides. Like `Source.tick` ([docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.2/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#tick)).

```
  val tickingSource: Source[String, Cancellable] = 
    Source.tick(initialDelay = 1.second, interval = 5.seconds, tick = "hello")
```

In your example, you need an incremented counter to be published, so you can attach more logic to the ticking source, e.g.

```
  val tickingSource: Source[Strict, Cancellable] =
    Source.tick(initialDelay = 1.second, interval = 5.seconds, tick = NotUsed)
      .zipWithIndex
      .map{ case (_, counter) ⇒ TextMessage(counter.toString) }
```

If you're interested in how the underlying `GraphStage` works, you can always take a look at `TickSource` code itself (see [github](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/impl/fusing/GraphStages.scala#L232)).
The main difference is that `TickSource` calls `push` in the `onTimer` callback (which comes from `TimerGraphStageLogic`, and which you can override).

Comment: And how to do it with `GraphStage` and `TimerGraphStageLogic`?

Comment: added info to the answer

Comment: Does not work for me as in `TimerGraphStageLogic` it says `not yet initialized: only setHandler is allowed in GraphStageLogic constructor`